# How to write variables to a temporary file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, temporary-files

I have been trying to write variables to a temporary text file but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/A453/_Codes_/APP CONFIG/Temp.py", line 102, in <module>
    ORXQC-IIHL2-6AV55-FIJEV-2""")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python34\lib\tempfile.py", line 399, in     func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

My Script is the Following:

```
import tempfile
TEMPDIR=tempfile.TemporaryFile()
TEMPDIR.write("""B5IB6-ELAZ1-RAPY9-V8X1I-3
OKXVB-Q8B9G-IT9ZF-MI4EQ-2
PLDZ6-769YT-YJSR4-682JT-7
H67L5-9HO4C-4UDSR-BYA14-6
Y73EC-S8OJG-O1APH-N41KM-3
JCYVV-UXNIN-9RGSU-WQ9SD-1
WL9AO-9BLI7-GXXGM-VESEU-2
VDLHT-IXMUY-V4FPU-V3IFZ-1
8CPVN-Z776Z-Y49J3-2C683-5
ORXQC-IIHL2-6AV55-FIJEV-2""")
Activation=input('Please Enter your Product Activation Key: ')
if Activation in TEMPDIR:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

Please help me overcome this error

Thanks

Comment: the same way as to regular file, I guess: `f = open(TEMPDIR, 'w'); f.write(something)`

Comment: Did you search your error and try the several solutions that come up based on that message you are receiving?

Comment: Did you try [these solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=TypeError%3A+%27str%27+does+not+support+the+buffer+interface) ?

Answer (score 10):

The default mode of `TemporaryFile` is `"w+b"`, e.g. binary. You have to provide the mode explicitly for text:

```
TEMPDIR = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode="w+")
```

Answer (score 1):

The default mode used to open the file returned by `TempFile` is `'w+b'`. The `b` in that string means it's opened in binary mode, and you need to pass `bytes` instances to its `write` method, rather than `str` instances like you're doing.

You have a few options. You could encode your string to `bytes`. Or alternatively, you could pass a mode to `TempFile` to have it open the file in text mode (so that `write` expects Unicode `str` instances). Using a proper mode is probably the better solution, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) explain that `tempfile` uses binary mode by default when opening a file to write to. Therefore, you can't write strings to it (this only works in text mode), only `bytes` objects.

So either override that default (as in Daniel's answer), or encode your strings with the appropriate encoding:

```
TEMPDIR.write("foo".encode("utf-8"))
```

or use a `bytes` object right away:

```
TEMPDIR.write(b"""B5IB6-ELAZ1-RAPY9-V8X1I-3...")
```